# RPi B+ How to expose status LEDs to outside of chasis?

Tags: rpi.gpio

I would like to expose status LEDs (OK, PWR, FDX, LNK, 10M) to outside of chasis without soldering extra cables to onboard LEDs. Is it possible to map those LEDs to free GPIOs and connect extra 5 LEDS to them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using device tree with a recent kernel you can re-route the disk activity (GPIO 47) and power LEDs (GPIO 35).  You can not re-route the other LEDs.  Perhaps use light pipes?

Edit /boot/config.txt and add the following entries.

```
dtparam=act_led_gpio=xxx
dtparam=pwr_led_gpio=yyy
```

where xxx and yyy are Broadcom GPIO numbers.

See /boot/overlays/README for details.